# Select items where ID present in another column MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of `albums`, each album has an `ID`.

I also have a table of `reviews`, each review is linked to a corresponding album through the column `albumID`.

I'm wondering how I can select all albums who's ID's are present in the reviews table.

I was thinking of selecting all albumId's from the reviews column then doing a `select where id in` but I feel like this would be horribly inefficient.

This is in MySQL

```
Albums Table
- ID

Reviews Table
- ID
- albumID
```

Desired result: All albums who have a review. (eg: All albums that have their ID present in the Reviews table)

Comment: try to post some table sample data and desired output

Comment: use a join or  exists statement.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach using a simple JOIN.  The inner join notation will only include records that exist in both tables.  It allows you to access data in both tables which may be useful  if you need data out of reviews too.

```
Select * from albums A
inner join reviews R
 on A.ID = R.AlbumID
```

This next approach is generally the fastest but you can only get data from albums. This uses what's known as a correlated sub query and is generally the fastest approach.

```
SELECT * from albums A
where exists (Select 1 from reviews R where A.ID = R.albumID)
```

and a third approach but generally the slowest... uses a concept called [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in).  The sub query here generates a list of ID's from reviews and only shows albums in that list.

```
Select * from albums where ID IN (SELECT albumID from Reviews)
```

Comment: *haha!* - I'm a bit dyxlesxic myself ;-) *at times*.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
select a.* from albums as a
inner join reviews as r
on r.albumID = a.ID
```